# Windows 8 administrator denied access to file

Tags: windows-8, permissions

I was working on a project with a library I've never used before (HaxeFlixel) as well as git for source control, and FlashDevelop as an IDE.

I'm not exactly sure how this happened, but there is now a folder in the build directory that doesn't give me permission to read or write to it. I can't open it, I can't delete it, I can't rename it, I can't even look at its properties because I don't have read access.

When I right click-properties, it says:

> "You must have read permissions to view the properties of this object"

When I click on the advanced button, it says:

> "Owner: unable to display current owner"

and lower down it says

> Click continue to attempt the operation with administrative permissions

And then it shows a "Continue" button with the UAC icon thing on it.

But when I click on that button, it reopens the same windows, only this time it doesn't show the "Owner" string nor the "Continue" button, it simply says this:

> You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings

This weird because there are no other users on this computer, which is a Microsoft Surface Pro. My account is definitely an administrator account (according to control panel anyways).

Also, not being able to read or write to my build directory is problematic to say the least.

Comment: Have you tried using Unlocker on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to discover the current owner of a folder?](http://superuser.com/questions/621884/is-it-possible-to-discover-the-current-owner-of-a-folder)

Comment: I don't know which program you're talking about, but I installed Take Ownership [here](http://www.intowindows.com/take-ownership-of-files-and-folders-in-windows-8/) and it still didn't work. I finally just decided to reboot my computer, and when it turned back on the entire folder was missing! Never found out who the owner was, but at least that folder won't be getting in my way anymore.